# Will rapidly changing iptables rules cause issues?

Tags: ubuntu, debian, iptables

I am writing a script that monitors different metrics (e.g. interface bandwidth usage) and changing `iptables` rules accordingly. These changes may occur at least 2x per second, up to `4 * number of interfaces` per second.

The thing is, I'm not sure how `iptables` handles rule changes. Are things recompiled and the script will tax the CPU hard? Or what happens to packets still being processed during rule change; will they get dropped? Those sorts of concerns.

Will rapidly changing iptables rules cause issues?

**EDIT**: For my specific application, all the rules are already in place. They're more of enabling or disabling (adding or removing) certain rules. In other words, the tables won't grow over time and get extremely large.

Comment: That is probably something you'll need to benchmark for yourself. In part it will depend on how large the ruleset / chain is, where you're adding/deleting rules (at the start, end or somewhere in the middle) , are you flushing complete chains and creating new ones, or just rules and what are the objectives of the changes. Possible rather than changing rules your objectives can be reached by acting on ipset sets  (adding/removing/storing many IP-addresses in an ipset allow/access/block list is much more efficient than creating/removing separate iptables rules for each of those IP's)

Comment: While I agree that testing is advisable, unless you're talking about UDP traffic with no integrity controls, it shouldn't matter too much if you lose a few packets. What I would be concerned about is the tables getting very large - that can introduce a significant lag.

Answer (score 2):

How do you change the rules?

Do you invoke the `iptables` command repeatedly? That will have significant performance impact, because how iptables work:

- Grab the whole netfilter tables/chains
- Perform ONE change as requested
- Load the whole netfilter tables/chains back into kernel

That will happen on *every single* `iptables` invocation.

The question is: What's the nature of changes you do to the rules?

If you're adding/removing rules based on source and/or destination addresses, you should use `ipset` instead.

But if you're adding/removing rules, say because you're changing other parameters on the fly (say, changing `rate` to match more/less frequently, change the QoS flags, etc.), then maybe `ipset` will not be suitable for you.

On the other hand, if your script perform changes *en masse*, also consider doing it this way:

- Grab the whole netfilter tables/chains

  - You can use `iptables-save` utility, or depending on what you write your script in, maybe there's a library that can do that for you
- Perform ALL changes you want in one go
- Load (commit) the whole netfilter tables/chains back to kernel

  - You can use `iptables-restore` utility, or similar to step 1, use a library that can do that for you

---

### EDIT:

Ah, because the rules are already in the table, you can use the [condition match](https://www.netfilter.org/documentation/HOWTO/netfilter-extensions-HOWTO-3.html#ss3.2) to turn them on/off.

Insert `-m condition --condition $NAME` into your `iptables` rule.

That will create a file, `/proc/net/ipt_condition/$NAME`. The match succeeds if the file contains `1`, and otherwise if the file contains `0`

(You can, of course, use negation `!` to invert the match.)

For example:

```
iptables -A INPUT -m condition --condition allow_880 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 880 -j ACCEPT
```

To enable the rule:

```
echo 1 > /proc/net/ipt_condition/allow_880
```

To disable:

```
echo 0 > /proc/net/ipt_condition/allow_880
```

(You're free to use any name you want, I recommend making them easily identifiable. There's a maximum length for the name but I don't recall what.)

#### Edit 1a:

If you've already built the table, the easiest way to edit is to save the output of `iptables-save`, edit it (add the condition matches for rules that need them), then load the whole file using `iptables-restore` or `iptables-apply`

Remember: 1 condition file can control more than 1 rule; you are not required to have 1 file per rule, unless you really want it that way.

#### Edit 1b:

As @A.B mentioned in the comments (thanks!), `-m condition` might not be a standard feature for your distro's built-in iptables; in such case, you'll likely need to install an additional package, for instance, `xtables-addons`.

(Sorry forgot about this because I'm on Gentoo and the `iptables` package on Gentoo simply follows what the kernel .config is.)

Comment: Condition match looks awesome! I had no idea this was a thing. Will test.

Comment: Note: `-m condition` is not available with the standard iptables installation (and is not documented in `man iptables-extensions`) but instead comes with the extra package `xtables-addons` as documented there: https://www.netfilter.org/projects/xtables-addons/index.html . On some distributions (eg: Debian) the kernel part comes as a DKMS package and has to be compiled for the kernel in use. It's then documented in `man xtables-addons`.

Answer (score 0):

Nftables might be better suited in this case.nftables is designed to be more efficient and scalable than iptables, especially with complex rule sets or frequent modifications. It provides better performance due to its integration into the Linux kernel and streamlined syntax.

Comment: Actually, _both_ iptables _and_ nftables are integrated in the kernel. But true, nftables is more streamlined than iptables.